# Why op amp is getting warm

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, heat

Below schematic is a voltage regulator circuit minus the compensations/filters parts (capacitors etc):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f32vhl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The amount of current the op amp is sinking is not more than ~2.6 mA but for some unknown reason the op amp is getting a little warm (~42-45°C).

What causing the op amp to heat up?

Datasheets:

- [MC33079](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC33078-D.PDF)
- [2SD1047](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/2sd1047.pdf)
- [TIP122](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TIP120-D.PDF)
- [LM317](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LM317-D.PDF)

Comment: Does the regulator work as intended?

Comment: @StefanWyss Yes it does work and it's not hot, just warm. I'm concerned because the heat may affect the input voltage offset...

Comment: Did you measure the 2.6mA?

Comment: @StefanWyss Yes I measured the LM317 output current before connecting it to the op amp.

Comment: But the Opamp has a -5V supply. So it could also drive to -5V. Why dont you measure the actual current through the diode?

Comment: @StefanWyss I just measured it again to make sure, and current was 1.4 mA. it's on the breadboard in front of me...

Comment: The datasheet you linked doesn't give the thermal impedance of the device, but it could be around 100C/W J-A.  You could get a few degrees rise from the Iq and the load current.  I don't know your ambient- What's the rise over ambient you're seeing? Where are you measuring the temperature? 42-45C at 25C ambient does sound excessive.

Comment: @JohnD The ambient is 24°C. I didn't measured with anything, it's just warms to touch feels like ~40°C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, lets do some calculation: Supply 30V with 1.5mA load and 5mA quiescent current, total 6.5mA. This is 200mW. With Tja 100deg/W this will be a delta T of 20deg C. So your amp will be at 44 deg C. You seem to have a good feeling for temperature ;-)

Comment: The junction will be at 44C, but the package may not.  Since there's no thermal impedance info in the linked datasheet and we don't know which package the OP is using  it's hard to say.

Comment: Ok, junction is not case temp, fair enough, But on a breadboard, Tja could be much higher than 100deg/W. I would expect it to be 200 deg/W.

Comment: Stefan, you can use HTML entities `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&deg;`, `&times;`, etc. as well as `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>` in the posts (but they don't work in the comments). SI standard recommends a space between the number and units for legibility (and normal writing: "99 bananas" and not "99bananas").

Comment: I forgot to ask; where in the datasheet the quiescent current is mentioned?

Comment: Page 3, bottom, Power supply current